# Cannot import provisioning profile into Xcode

Tags: xcode, ios5, provisioning-profile

I am a beginner of iOS development. I am helping to archive an .ipa file for an in-house iPad app. I am not the Admin/Agent so I received one certificate file plus two provisioning files. I installed the certificate using Keychain Access, which waas successfully. And I can see the certificate appear on the Organizer's TEAMS group as well.

But I was failed to import the two provisioning profiles. I dragged them to Xcode icon, nothing happened. I clicked the "import" button on Organizer and selected the profiles, nothing happened... Anyone knows why? I hope there's at least some pop-up warning messages so that I know what's wrong, but I just cannot see the profiles added to my list.

Comment: can't you see your provisioning profile in project ->Build Settings -> Code Sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out and I hope it would be helpful for others.
My company use Exchange Server for emails and it seems that it would somehow affect the provisioning profiles. So I asked the admin to zip the profiles before sending and the problems was solved.